# Where will the reference to all sockets be stored in linux kernel? Is there a table in kernel contain that

Tags: android, linux, sockets, kernel

There are different processes running that creates inet sockets. Where are the references to these sockets stored in linux kernel. Is there a table in which these opened sockets are stored. Can we access it to get all the socket reference?

Comment: For what purpose? You can't do anything useful with another process's socket FD.

Comment: I doubt a non-system app has permission to do that.

Comment: I am not going to access it from application layer. I am writing a kernel module to collect socket information from the kernel.